# How to preprocess and decompress .gz file on Azure Data Lake store?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Will USQL support to Compress and Decompress a file.?

I would like decompress a compressed file to perform some validations and once they are passed, would like to compress the data to new file.

Comment: Azure SQL Data Warehouse can deal with gzipped files natively.  Is the data highly structured, ie could be inserted into a table?  If so, Polybase can deal with gzipped files natively, so it would be easy to create an external table definition over the gzipped file(s), inspect them etc.  The advantage of this would be no extra custom code is required, the disadvantage is well you would have to use another product, Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Comment: @wbob, Do we have any possible options with USQL?

Answer (score 3):

In addition, doing automatic compression on `OUTPUT` is on the roadmap. Please add your vote to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13418367-support-gzip-on-output-as-well

Comment: It is now available in Preview. At the top of your U-SQL script add the line: `SET @@FeaturePreviews = "GZipOutput:on";`

Answer (score 2):

According to the main [EXTRACT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621320.aspx) article, U-SQL `EXTRACT` method automatically recognises the GZip format, so you don't need to do anything special.

> **Extraction from compressed data**
>
> In general, the files are passed as is
>   to the UDO. One exception is that EXTRACT will recognize GZip
>   compressed files with the file extension .gz and automatically
>   decompress them as part of the extraction process. The actual UDO will
>   see the uncompressed data. For any other compression scheme, users
>   will have to write their own custom extractor. Note that U-SQL has an
>   upper limit of 4GB on a GZip compressed file. If you apply your
>   EXTRACT expression to a file larger than this limit, the error
>   E_RUNTIME_USER_MAXCOMPRESSEDFILESIZE is being raised during the
>   compilation of the job.

It looks like this feature has been available for a while, but was updated in Nov 2016 to introduce the 4GB limit.  See [here](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2016/2016_10_16/USQL_Release_Notes_2016_10_16.md).

Here is a simple example which converts a gzipped, comma-separated file to pipe-separated:

```
DECLARE @file1 string = @"/input/input.csv.gz";

@file =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            col2 string,
            col3 string
    FROM @file1
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent : true);


@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @file;


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.txt"
ORDER BY col1
//FETCH 500 ROWS
USING Outputters.Text(quoting : false, delimiter : '|');
```

Comment: if i have 1 zip file that has 10 CSV files, each representing a different data set, how do i extract the csv and use it with usql or another product?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' this is a separate question.  Post it and I'm sure someone will help you.