# Possible to use .zip file with multiple .csv files?

Tags: u-sql

Is it possible using U-SQL to unzip a zip folder with multiple .csv files and process them?

Each file has a different schema.

Comment: What format are your zip files in?  It's worth bearing in mind `EXTRACT` can natively deal with gzip files, no extra programming required, as per this [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711229/how-to-preprocess-and-decompress-gz-file-on-azure-data-lake-store/42718898#42718898).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you've got two problems here.

1. Extract from a ZIP file.
2. Deal with inner varying contents.

To answer your question. Is it possible?... **Yes**.

How?... You'd need to write a user defined extractor to do it.

First check out the MSDN extractors page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621320.aspx

The class for the extractor needs to inherit from IExtractor with methods that iterate over the archive contents.

Then to output each inner file in turn pass a file name to the extractor so you can define the columns for each dataset.

Source: https://ryansimpson.net/2016/10/15/query-zipfile-adla/

Another option would be to use Azure Data Factory to perform the UnZip operation in a custom activity and output the CSV contents to ADL Store. This would involve some more engineering though and an Azure Batch Service.

Hope this helps.