# Compress Data Lake file to GZ with USQL custom outputter

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a requirement to compress Data Lake file to GZ compression. Have seen that outputters on USQL do not directly support this. In my earlier post [How to preprocess and decompress .gz file on Azure Data Lake store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711229/how-to-preprocess-and-decompress-gz-file-on-azure-data-lake-store) @Michael Rys mentioned that automatic compression capability is currently on road map. Does any one have idea on Implementing custom code to achieve this..?

Comment: Data Factory would support this I think.  Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @wBob I tried with DataFactory it worked. Requirement was to achive the same with UQL custom code. Do u have any example on this..?

Comment: No.  Why write custom code to do something you can already do?

Comment: @wBob We feel better in monitoring and logging the USQL Job activity through power shell and handle the same in SSIS packages. And the requirement is  on-demand and DL soruce files location may change based on business needs. In DF this needs redeployment of Data sets. Control over the logging is also one concern here. I tried to compress the file with USQL custom outputter. But the Job is giving the error- 
OUTPUT currently does not support file formats: 'gzip'.

Answer (score 0):

The compressed output is now available on preview:

https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2017/2017_Summer/USQL_Release_Notes_2017_Summer.md#automatic-gzip-compression-on-output-statement-is-now-in-preview-opt-in-statement-is-provided

Comment: Is this still a preview only feature? I cannot find documentation in the ADLA docs, and my client does not want preview features in their production space.