# Unzip .gz files from azure data lake using python

Tags: python-3.x, azure

I am trying to unzip a .gz file stored in azure data lake.

```
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib

Tenant_Id = '####'
Client_Key = '####'
Client_Id = '####' 
token = lib.auth(tenant_id=Tenant_Id, client_secret=Client_Key, client_id=Client_Id)

store_name = 'root'
# Connecting to adl
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=store_name)
# List of .gz files 
list_of_gz_files = adl.ls('/test/2018')
# Would like to uzip files present inside list_of_gz_files list
```

Is it possible to unzip them using gzip etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide 3 options here to decompress zip files in the ADL.

1.Use Azure Data Factory to unzip the files using the [copy file activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) (native support for gzip files).

[image]

2.Use [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) in ADF. Create job in azure batch and access data lake to unzip the file with python code.(Use [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) package)

3.Use custom extractor in U-SQL,please refer to this trace:[How to preprocess and decompress .gz file on Azure Data Lake store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711229/how-to-preprocess-and-decompress-gz-file-on-azure-data-lake-store)

Comment: Thanks for the response Jay, Is there are way to do it programatically using Python and azure libraries.

Comment: @RaviKiran Based on my research,there is no direct such azure sdk. So,maybe you could use above second solution to use gzip python package.